# How do I return JSON only from Azure Functions (dotnet5)

Tags: .net, azure-functions, .net-5, azure-http-trigger

I have a set of HttpTrigger Azure Functions in dotnet5 and I want to return JSON from those Azure Functions. I'm using `return new OkObjectResult(myObject)` but that is not providing JSON but rather the JSON is in the "Value" element of the JSON returned
i.e. the results look a bit like

```
{
  "Value": {
    "MyValueOne": true,
    "MyValueTwo": 8
  },
  "Formatters": [],
  "ContentTypes": [],
  "DeclaredType": null,
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

as opposed to the expected

```
{
    "MyValueOne": true,
    "MyValueTwo": 8
}
```

I've gone down a couple paths with different return objects, but they always seem to be having these extra values and the JSON I want returned usually wrapped up in a Value or Content with in other JSON, for example:
JsonResult(myObject) OR
ContentResult() { Content = serialisedVersionOfMyObject }

I even tried the HttpResponseMessage path; but ran into trouble with the HttpTrigger and expected return of Tast

I feel like I'm missing something simple; what is the expected / desired / straight-forward way of returning "just json" from an Azure Function?

Comment: Azure function .net 5 returns the `HttpResponseData` as output of Http trigger function. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#http-trigger)

Comment: Awesome; do you want to put that as an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Of course the frustrating thing is how hard that was to find; and that when you create the function it has the return type of Task<IActionResult> (which is where I was getting caught up; trying to return the type that visual studio created as the signature)

Comment: Sure, let me add as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure function .net 5 returns the HttpResponseData as output of Http trigger function. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#http-trigger).

Text from the documentation:

HTTP triggers translates the incoming HTTP request message into an `HttpRequestData` object that is passed to the function. This object provides data from the request, including Headers, Cookies, Identities, URL, and optional a message Body. This object is a representation of the HTTP request object and not the request itself.

Likewise, the function returns an `HttpResponseData` object, which provides data used to create the HTTP response, including message StatusCode, Headers, and optionally a message Body.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

if you need to return a object (serialized), try to do this:

you will have one parameter in you Azure Function, the type and name are (HttpRequestData req), now you need to use this to create you response:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(itemData); <-- itemData = your object

return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help someone, it's related to [Felipe Augusto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8104755/felipe-augusto) answer.

---

If you use `WriteAsJsonAsync()` you must **not** add the header `Content-Type` manually:

```
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

That's because `WriteAsJsonAsync()` already does that, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsejsonextensions.writeasjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> Write the specified value as JSON to the response body.
> The response content-type will be set to `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

If you try adding the header, you'll get a `k8s.Autorest.HttpOperationException`:

```
Error: Cannot add value because header 'Content-Type' does not support multiple values.
```